# @RestControllerAdvice vs @ControllerAdvice

Tags: spring

- What are the major difference between @RestControllerAdvice and @ControllerAdvice ??
- Is it we should always use @RestControllerAdvice for rest services and @ControllerAdvice MVC ?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`@RestControllerAdvice` is just a syntactic sugar for `@ControllerAdvice` + `@ResponseBody`, you can look [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestControllerAdvice.html).

> Is it we should always use @RestControllerAdvice for rest services and
>   @ControllerAdvice MVC?

Again, as mentioned above, `@ControllerAdvice` can be used even for REST web services as well, but you need to additionally use `@ResponseBody`.

Comment: can you give us an example ?

Answer (score 25):

In addition, we can just understand it as:

`@RestControler` = `@Controller` + `@ResponseBody`

`@RestControllerAdvice` = `@ControllerAdvice` + `@ResponseBody`.

Keeping in mind that `@RestControllerAdvice` is more convenient annotation for handling Exception with RestfulApi.

Example os usage:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class WebRestControllerAdvice {
  
  @ExceptionHandler(CustomNotFoundException.class)
  public ResponseMsg handleNotFoundException(CustomNotFoundException ex) {
    return new ResponseMsg(ex.getMessage());
  }
}
```

In that case any exception instanceOf CustomNotFoundException will be thrown in body of response.

Example extracted here:
https://grokonez.com/spring-framework/spring-mvc/use-restcontrolleradvice-new-features-spring-framework-4-3

Comment: Did you mean "@RestControllerAdvice" in this statement: "Keeping in mind that @ControllerAdvice is more convenient annotation for handling Exception with RestfulApi."

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: If you want to modify the status, or add headers in the wrapping ResponseEntity, how would you do that with `@RestControllerAdvice`?

Answer (score 5):

**Exception:** A good REST API should handle the exception properly and send the proper response to the user. The user should not be rendered with any unhandled exception.
A REST API developer will have two requirements related to error handling.

1. Common place for Error handling
2. Similar Error Response body with a proper HTTP status code across APIs

**@RestControllerAdvice is the combination of both @ControllerAdvice and @ResponseBody**

The @ControllerAdvice annotation was first introduced in Spring 3.2.

We can use the **@ControllerAdvice annotation for handling exceptions in the RESTful Services but we need to add @ResponseBody separately**.

Note:
**GlobalExceptionHandler was annotated with @ControllerAdvice**, thus it is going to intercept exceptions from controllers accross the application.

Answer (score 5):

The differences between @RestControllerAdvice and @ControllerAdvice is :

> `@RestControllerAdvice` = `@ControllerAdvice` + `@ResponseBody`. - we can
> use in **REST web services**.
>
> `@ControllerAdvice` - We can use in both **MVC** and **Rest web services**, need to
> provide the ResponseBody if we use this in Rest web services.

**For Example :**

**Exception Class:**

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends Exception{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public ResourceNotFoundException(String message){
        super(message);
    }
}
```

**usage of the above exception in Rest Web Service.**

```
 @RestControllerAdvice
 public class MyRestControllerAdviceHandler {
     
 @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
      public ResponseMsg resourceNotFoundException(ResourceNotFoundException ex) {
        ResponseMsg resMsg = new ResponseMsg(ex.getMessage());
        return resMsg;
      }
    
}
```

**usage of the above exception in MVC.**

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> resourceNotFoundException(ResourceNotFoundException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use @ControllerAdvice and return your error object from a method then it will look for a view with the name of your error object so instead of returning the expected response it will return 404 for not founding a view page with that name

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomizedExceptionHandler {
@ExceptionHandler({ UserNotFoundException.class })
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public ExceptionResponce handleUserNotException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) throws Exception {
    ExceptionResponce exceptionResponce = new ExceptionResponce(new Date(), ex.getMessage(),
            request.getDescription(false));
    return exceptionResponce;


}
```

}

As in the above code, I want to return 400 (BAD_REQUEST) but
instead of 400, it is returning 404(NOT_FOUND)

[image]

You can solve this issue by using any of the below ways

1. add @ResponseBody to your method or class.
2. Use @RestControllerAdvice.
3. Or you can wrap your error object in ResponseEntity.

After using either of the above ways it returns the correct response
[image]