# Spring boot handle type mismatch errors

Tags: spring, spring-boot, bean-validation

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.5, and I have a class that is mapped to data submitted from a form. The class has an integer field:

```
class FormData {
   private Integer id;
   ...
}
```

When I send a payload with the wrong type, e.g:

```
{
  id: "aaaa"
}
```

Spring silently returns a 400 status, no exception is thrown, and nothing is printed to the console. I would like to somehow catch this when this happens, so that I would be able to return a proper custom error. I basically use bean validation for all of my other validations, but I can't find a way to apply it for a type mismatch.

Thanks.

Comment: Share your controller as well

Answer (score 1):

This invalid parameter type conversion throws a [`TypeMismatchException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/TypeMismatchException.html), that you can handle with a method annotated with [`@ExceptionHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html), for example, like this :

```java
@ExceptionHandler(TypeMismatchException.class)
@ResponseBody
public MyErrorResponse handleTypeMismatchException(TypeMismatchException typeMismatchException) {
    // create my error response
}
```

You can place this method inside one controller (in which case it's going to handle only exceptions thrown by this controller), or inside a class annotated with [`@ControllerAdvice`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) (so it will be generalized to all your controllers).

Comment: It doesn't work for me - TypeMismatchException is not catched in my ControllerAdvice

Comment: @Matley Is the ControllerAdvice being picked up by component scanning? Is it targetting a subset of Controllers with options like 'basePackages' or 'annotations'?

Comment: of course! Are you sure that exception thrown during deserialization (casting String to Long in my case) should be catched in my ControllerAdvice in ExceptionHandler?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Controller will throw `TypeMismatchException` for your case.

To handle any exception at controller level you can annotate the method with `@ExceptionHandler`

Something like this

```
@ExceptionHandler(TypeMismatchException.class)
@ResponseBody
public SampleObject handleTypeMismatchException(TypeMismatchException typeMismatchException) {
    ...
}
```

You can also configure Global Exception Handling With `@ControllerAdvice.`

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    /** Provides handling for exceptions throughout this service. */
    @ExceptionHandler({ TypeMismatchException.class })
    public final ResponseEntity<ApiError> handleException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
        TypeMismatchException tme = (TypeMismatchException) ex;
        return handleTypeMismatchException(tme, headers, status, request);

    }


    /** Customize the response for TypeMismatchException. */
    protected ResponseEntity<ApiError> handleTypeMismatchException(TypeMismatchException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        List<String> errorMessages = ex.getErrors()
                .stream()
                .map(contentError -> contentError.getObjectName() + " " + contentError.getDefaultMessage())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, new ApiError(errorMessages), headers, status, request);
    }

    /** A single place to customize the response body of all Exception types. */
    protected ResponseEntity<ApiError> handleExceptionInternal(Exception ex, ApiError body, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        if (HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.equals(status)) {
            request.setAttribute(WebUtils.ERROR_EXCEPTION_ATTRIBUTE, ex, WebRequest.SCOPE_REQUEST);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(body, headers, status);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own `@ControllerAdvice` class and handle `TypeMismatchException` like this

```
@ExceptionHandler({
        MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class,
        TypeMismatchException.class
})
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> handleException(TypeMismatchException e) {
    Map<String, String> errorResponse = new HashMap<>();

    errorResponse.put("message", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    errorResponse.put("status", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.toString());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

refer to [Custom Error Messages in Spring REST API](https://www.amitph.com/spring-rest-api-custom-error-messages/) for more

Answer (score 0):

There can be another error if you are using a complex JSON. In my case, I had something similar with `List<BigDecimal>` and I had `HttpMessageNotReadableException` instead of `TypeMismatchException`

I used a custom validation handler with `@RestControllerAdvice` (actually you can use `@ControllerAdvice` as well). What is the difference between these two annotations you can find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43124517/5631885

If you are using `extends` strategy, like:

```
@ControllerAdvice    
public class ValidationExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler
```

Just need to override `handleHttpMessageNotReadable` method

```
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(
        HttpMessageNotReadableException ex,
        HttpHeaders headers,
        HttpStatus status,
        WebRequest request) {

    Map<String, Object> body = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    body.put(TIMESTAMP_KEY, new Date());
    body.put(STATUS_KEY, status.value());
    body.put(ERROR_KEY, ex.getCause().getMessage());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(body, headers, status);
}
```

Otherwise, go with `@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)` annotation above the method.

Answer (score -2):

Try HttpMessageNotReadableException

Worked for me

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.